# Une traduction pour « Ik wordt van het kastje naar de muur gestuurd »

Tags: traduction, expressions, néerlandais

Je cherche une traduction pour une expression néerlandaise. « Je suis envoyé de l’armoire au mur. » On dit ça quand on est client à une compagnie qui manque à ses devoirs. Voici un exemple avec au-dessous une explication.

Quelqu’un achète un aspirateur, et après le premier emploi il semble d’être en panne malgré le soin de l’acheteur. Il appelle donc le numéro du magasin où il l’a acheté, mais on lui répond qu’il doit appeler un autre numéro pour trouver quelqu’un qui remet son aspirateur en état. Quand il appelle ce nouveau numéro, on lui dit qu’il doit parler avec encore une autre personne, et ainsi de suite.

Bref, une entreprise fait une faute, et par la suite un usager a besoin de quelqu’un qui lui aide, mais personne ne se porte responsable pour ce qui se produit. La façon de dire exprime un peu de mécontentement.

Savez-vous comment de traduire ça ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pour exprimer le fait qu'aucune entreprise ne veut accepter sa responsabilité, on peut dire que les entreprises:

> - se renvoient la balle
> - se défaussent
> - se rejettent la faute

Note que les deux dernières expressions ne traduisent pas vraiment l'idée du client se faisant [balader](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11710/1129) d'une entreprise à l'autre.

Comment: Je ne voulais pas dire que ces sont des entreprises qui ne se portent pas garantes, mais plutôt que les gens qui y travaillent, ou des équipes renvoient des clients pour échapper des responsabilités.  Hormis cette petite chose, vous avez bien répondu ma question.

Answer (score 6):

Je ne connais pas d'expression figée traduisant cette impression, mais le verbe *balader* peut avoir ce sens.  Donc quelque chose du genre *ils m'ont baladé de service en service*.